# How to track more than 400 keywords using Twitter Stream API?

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

The question is simply the title.

Please don't tell me to go for a Twitter Data reseller like Gnip or Datasift as they're so expensive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run more than one twitter stream, there is no other way around to solve this issue. For running multiple streamer basically you need a dedicated twitter user, ip address and registered application for each streamer.